# What is the need for ::after when trying to highlight a table column in CSS?

Tags: css

So for highlighting rows in a table, we only need tr:hover and you have to set a background-color that has has an opacity of less than 1 to appear as if it's a highlight.

**But for highlighting columns, why is there a need for `::after` or `::before` and the `content` part in this CSS?** This code is currently working fine but I just want to understand what they're for.

```
table {
        border:  1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;  /*no borders*/
        width: 75%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        font-family: "Gill Sans", sans-serif;
        z-index: 1;             /*table is over the highlight*/
        overflow: hidden;       /*cuts off the column highlight as to not overflow*/
    }
    
tr:hover {                  /*highlights rows*/
        background-color: rgba(195, 164, 255, 0.25);
        z-index: -1;
    }
td:hover::after {           /*highlights columns*/
        background-color: rgba(195, 164, 255, 0.25);
        content: "";
        height: 10000px;    
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;  
        top: -5000px;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: -1;
    }
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<body>
<h2>Timetable</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Monday</th>
        <th>Tuesday</th>
        <th>Wednesday</th>
        <th>Thursday</th>
        <th>Friday</th>
        <th>Saturday</th>
        <th>Sunday</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>0900-1000</th>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Jia</td>
        <td>Jesse</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>1000-1100</th>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Jia</td>
        <td>Kaidan</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi. Show your HTML code, too. So that we to see the output.

Comment: This is just a slightly hacky way of highlighting a column. When the user hovers over a cell a very tall absolutely positioned pseudo element is positioned way above the cell, and extends all the way down - for 10000px in all. Someone has taken a guess that that will be (more than) tall enough for the table. The effect is it makes it look as though all the cells in that column have been highlighted.

Comment: @AHaworth But what's the ::after for? And the 'content' part?
Why can't it just be
`td:hover {
     background-color: rgba(195, 164, 255, 0.25);
     height: 10000px;    
     left: 0;
     position: absolute;  
     top: -5000px;
     width: 100%;
     z-index: -1;
 }`

Without the content and ::after

Comment: You dont want the actual cell (the td) to become huge, you want it to stay where it is. So, we leave the td alone when it is hovered except we add an after pseudo element, positioned absolutely so it doesn't alter the positioning of anything else, we make it hugely tall and we set it back z-index: -1 so it appears behind all the cells it is going to go behind. A before pseudo element has to have content, but in this case we just want it to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

**`::after`** and **`::before`** are `pseudo-elements`. A **`pseudo-element`** is used to style specified parts of an element, and they're especified, as a rule, with double colons `::`; this distinguishes `pseudo-classes` (with single colon `:`) from pseudo-elements (since `CSS3`).

**`Pseudo-classes`** let you apply a style to an element not only in relation to the content of the document tree, but also in relation to external factors like hover.

`::before` and `::after` create a pseudo-element that is the first or the last child of the selected element, respectively. That means, that this `pseudo-elements` are contained by the element and thus don't apply to [replaced elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element).

The property **`content`** replaces an element with a generated value. For example, content could be an icon:

```css
.test::after {
  content: "♥";
 }
```

```html
<div class='test'></div>
```

Or the quotes of a text:

```css
.test::before {
  content: open-quote;
  color: lime;
}
.test::after {
  content: close-quote;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
 <div class='test'>This is a quoted text with pseudo-elements</div>
```

Or even a linear gradient:

```css
.test::after {
  content: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5);
}
```

```html
<div class='test'></div>
```

When creating one of this `after/before pseudo-elements`, It's necessary to add the `content` property. So that's why you will sometimes see `content: ""`. Look at this `::before` with no `content` property:

```css
.test::before {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class='test'></div>
```

Well, you probably didn't see anything. Now the same code, with `content: ""` property:

```css
.test::before {
    content: "";
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: red;
    position: fixed;
  }
```

```html
<div class='test'></div>
```

Regarding to your question, there's no need to add `::after` or `::before` to highlight the columns. What you're doing in your `::after` element is creating a very big "container" when user hovers over a `td`, so you're "highlighting" the entire page, not only the columns.

You could do:

Highlight al the `td` when on `hover` over `tr`:

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /*no borders*/
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", sans-serif;
  z-index: 1;
  /*table is over the highlight*/
  overflow: hidden;
  /*cuts off the column highlight as to not overflow*/
}

tr:hover {
  /*highlights rows*/
  background-color: rgba(195, 164, 255, 0.25);
  z-index: -1;
}

tr:hover>td {
  /*highlights columns*/
  background-color: rgba(195, 164, 255, 0.9);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>Monday</th>
    <th>Tuesday</th>
    <th>Wednesday</th>
    <th>Thursday</th>
    <th>Friday</th>
    <th>Saturday</th>
    <th>Sunday</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>0900-1000</th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Jia</td>
    <td>Jesse</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>1000-1100</th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Jia</td>
    <td>Kaidan</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Highlight only the `td` when on `hover`:

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /*no borders*/
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", sans-serif;
  z-index: 1;
  /*table is over the highlight*/
  overflow: hidden;
  /*cuts off the column highlight as to not overflow*/
}

tr:hover {
  /*highlights rows*/
  background-color: rgba(195, 164, 255, 0.25);
  z-index: -1;
}

td:hover {
  /*highlights columns*/
  background-color: rgba(195, 164, 255, 0.9);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>Monday</th>
    <th>Tuesday</th>
    <th>Wednesday</th>
    <th>Thursday</th>
    <th>Friday</th>
    <th>Saturday</th>
    <th>Sunday</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>0900-1000</th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Jia</td>
    <td>Jesse</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>1000-1100</th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Jia</td>
    <td>Kaidan</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you want to do this whith `pseudo-elements`, this is what you should do:

Highlight al the `td` when on `hover` over `tr` with `pseudo-elements`:

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /*no borders*/
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", sans-serif;
  z-index: 1;
  /*table is over the highlight*/
  overflow: hidden;
  /*cuts off the column highlight as to not overflow*/
}

tr:hover {
  /*highlights rows*/
  background-color: rgba(195, 164, 255, 0.25);
  z-index: -1;
}
tr:hover>td {
  position:relative;
}
tr:hover>td::before {
  /*highlights columns*/
  background-color: rgba(195, 164, 255, 0.9);
  content: "";
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>Monday</th>
    <th>Tuesday</th>
    <th>Wednesday</th>
    <th>Thursday</th>
    <th>Friday</th>
    <th>Saturday</th>
    <th>Sunday</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>0900-1000</th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Jia</td>
    <td>Jesse</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>1000-1100</th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Jia</td>
    <td>Kaidan</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Highlight only the `td` when on `hover` with `pseudo-elements`:

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /*no borders*/
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", sans-serif;
  z-index: 1;
  /*table is over the highlight*/
  overflow: hidden;
  /*cuts off the column highlight as to not overflow*/
}

tr:hover {
  /*highlights rows*/
  background-color: rgba(195, 164, 255, 0.25);
  z-index: -1;
}

tr:hover>td {
  position: relative;
}

td:hover::before {
  /*highlights columns*/
  background-color: rgba(195, 164, 255, 0.9);
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>Monday</th>
    <th>Tuesday</th>
    <th>Wednesday</th>
    <th>Thursday</th>
    <th>Friday</th>
    <th>Saturday</th>
    <th>Sunday</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>0900-1000</th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Jia</td>
    <td>Jesse</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>1000-1100</th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Jia</td>
    <td>Kaidan</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In both examples with `pseudo-elements`, notice the `index: -1`, so it's placed underneath. Also you need to add a `position: relative` to the `td`. `::before` or `::after` are `position: absolute`, so when `top,left,right, or bottom` of the `pseudo-element`, it is placed relatively to the `td` container and doesn't get off the "flow" of the container. See this example without `position: relative` on the `td`, where the `pseudo-element` is positioned to the top of the page and is actually the full width and height (similar to your code):

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /*no borders*/
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", sans-serif;
  z-index: 1;
  /*table is over the highlight*/
  overflow: hidden;
  /*cuts off the column highlight as to not overflow*/
}

tr:hover {
  /*highlights rows*/
  background-color: rgba(195, 164, 255, 0.25);
  z-index: -1;
}
tr:hover>td::before {
  /*highlights columns*/
  background-color: rgba(195, 164, 255, 0.9);
  content: "";
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>Monday</th>
    <th>Tuesday</th>
    <th>Wednesday</th>
    <th>Thursday</th>
    <th>Friday</th>
    <th>Saturday</th>
    <th>Sunday</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>0900-1000</th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Jia</td>
    <td>Jesse</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>1000-1100</th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Jia</td>
    <td>Kaidan</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```